# how to do non uniform groupby in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

pd.groupby works fine for single column, but as soon as I add another column in by field, it gives results which are not consistent. Let me explain

If I have a dataframe with three columns,where I want to group using 2 columns (via qcut).

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.rand(10),'B':np.random.rand(10),'C':np.rando
m.rand(10)})
```

**Sample Output**

```
A   B   C
0   0.702505    0.078116    0.861276
1   0.474526    0.306926    0.373893
2   0.267395    0.441987    0.070313
3   0.934065    0.426689    0.782238
4   0.699563    0.245129    0.767107
5   0.399163    0.387137    0.381213
6   0.796172    0.950839    0.625333
7   0.121071    0.742237    0.512383
8   0.292286    0.537574    0.634266
9   0.314205    0.082177    0.983505


A               C              
(0.437, 0.934]  (0.512, 0.767]     0.597984
                (0.767, 0.984]     0.252402
                [0.0703, 0.512]    0.306926
[0.121, 0.437]  (0.512, 0.767]     0.537574
                (0.767, 0.984]     0.082177
                [0.0703, 0.512]    0.523787
```

**Check buckets here**

If I do bucketing normally I would get above output

```
pd.groupby(df,by=[pd.qcut(df['A'],2),pd.qcut(df['C'],3)]).mean()
```

But If I try to do bucketing in two steps. First bucket A and then take one of the groups of A bucket and get C bucket. This time the bucket boundaries of C are different.

```
data3=pd.groupby(df,pd.qcut(df['A'],2)).get_group('[0.121, 0.437]')
pd.groupby(data3,pd.qcut(data3['C'],3)).mean()



    A   B   C
C           
[0.0703, 0.425]     0.333279    0.414562    0.225763
(0.425, 0.594]  0.121071    0.742237    0.512383
(0.594, 0.984]  0.303246    0.309875    0.808885
```

Why the mismatch in second doing grouping one by one in A then C vs doing them together. Is it a bug or feature? Normally multi grouping should proceed in this fashion. First take out elements satisfying predicate 'A' and then use those groups to apply 'C' grouping.

It seems to be cutting both equally. C first and then B!!!

Comment: Can you clean up your code? It looks really messy and not at all clear what you're coing.

Comment: added some more comments...hopefully this is helpful. It seems like pandas does incorrect bucketing.

Comment: In simple words ==> When we bucket on two columns, I don't want the second column  (or inner column) cut points two be exactly same for all groups of outer column (first column). The cutting of second column should be done based on the actual data you get in actual groups of first column buckets.

Comment: This is a very simple feature and although it can easily be done via loops, whats the point of using pandas then???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ugly way to do this is via lambda function
Consider my dataframe

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randn(10),'b':np.random.randn(10),'c':np.random.randn(10)})   

 d1=pd.groupby(df,pd.qcut(df['a'],3)).agg(lambda x:   pd.groupby(df[df['a'].isin(x)],pd.qcut(df[df['a'].isin(x)]['c'],3)))
```

This will create a dataframe with keys of 'a' buckets. The values will contain separate groups based on cuts in 'c'. So the cuts in C are separate from cuts in 'A'

```
print d1
print d1['a'][0].mean()
print d1['a'][1].mean()
Solutions
    a
```

a

```
[-1.809, -0.403]  <pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object a...
(-0.403, -0.148]  <pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object a...
(-0.148, 0.466]   <pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object a...
                    a         b         c
c                                            
[-1.25, -1.117] -1.651242  0.699280 -1.183546
(-1.117, 0.256] -0.495549 -1.098577  0.255841
(0.256, 1.793]  -0.403244  0.307497  1.792965
                          a         b         c
c                                              
[-1.634, -0.951]  -0.222313  1.589451 -1.633914
(-0.951, -0.0707] -0.148088 -1.180386 -0.609345
(-0.0707, 1.0067] -0.274481  0.772706  1.006701
```

Comment: notice that in both buckets the cuts of 'c' are different

Answer (score 0):

The results are different because you are providing the `groupby` function different data.

In the first case, you are creating buckets on all the values in `df['C']` and grouping with the buckets for  `df['A']`. However, when you are doing the bucketing in two steps, you are applying `qcut` to the subset of values in cloumn C that are in the `data3` dataframe, i.e.:

```
C
0.070313
0.381213
0.512383
0.634266
0.983505
```

Since this is not the same, `qcut` creates different buckets, and therefore you get different groupings.

Comment: that should be one of the behaviours of groupby. apply qcut to subset of values in column C. Coz already it's been cut into 2 parts via 'A' cut

Comment: is it possible to do grouping via 'A', and then for each of those groups apply grouping to column 'C' via map / lambda's?